# How to go inside the loop again

Tags: python-3.x

```
money =20

items = {'apple': 2, 'banana': 4, 'orange': 6}
for item_name in items:
    print('--------------------------------------------------')

    print("You have "+ str(money)+" dollars in your wallet")

    print('Each ' + item_name + ' costs ' + str(items[item_name]) + ' dollars')

    input_count = input('How many ' + item_name + 's do you want?: ')
    print('You will buy ' + input_count + ' ' + item_name + 's')

    count = int(input_count)
    total_price = items[item_name] * count
    print('The total price is ' + str(total_price) + ' dollars')


    if money >= total_price:
        print("You have bought "+str(input_count)+" "+str(item_name)+"s")

        money = money-total_price
    elif money < total_price:
        print("You do not have enough money")
        print("You cannot buy that many"+str(item_name)+"s")

print(str(money)+" dollars left in your wallet")
input("do want to buy somehing else: ")

if input() =="yes":
```

Output:

```
You have 20 dollars in your wallet
Each banana costs 4 dollars
How many bananas do you want?: 2
You will buy 2 bananas
The total price is 8 dollars
You have bought 2 bananas
-----------------------------------
You have 12 dollars in your wallet
Each apple costs 2 dollars
How many apples do you want?: 2
You will buy 2 apples
The total price is 4 dollars
You have bought 2 apples
-----------------------------------
You have 8 dollars in your wallet
Each orange costs 6 dollars
How many oranges do you want?: 1
You will buy 1 oranges
The total price is 6 dollars
You have bought 1 oranges
2 dollars left in your wallet
```

**2 dollars left in your wallet**  so here still we have left 2 dollars and I want to enter again in the loop:

Like using print("do you want to buy something else") if user enter yes then goto again inside the for loop if no then quit the program.

But I am getting difficulties to make like this

Comment: How about *another* loop outside all of what you have? Loops *can* be nested.

Comment: hey @Someprogrammerdude can you please write the code?

Comment: @anurag: requests for free work are discouraged here. We think people learn better if they try for themselves, are we also do not want Stack Overflow to get a reputation as a platform where posters do not need to make any prior attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but I think you could do something like:

```
money =20
items = {'apple': 2, 'banana': 4, 'orange': 6} 

while True:
    for item_name in items:
        print('--------------------------------------------------')

        print("You have "+ str(money)+" dollars in your wallet")

        print('Each ' + item_name + ' costs ' + str(items[item_name]) + 'dollars')

        input_count = input('How many ' + item_name + 's do you want?: ')
        print('You will buy ' + input_count + ' ' + item_name + 's')

        count = int(input_count)
        total_price = items[item_name] * count
        print('The total price is ' + str(total_price) + ' dollars')


        if money >= total_price:
            print("You have bought "+str(input_count)+""+str(item_name)+"s")

            money = money-total_price
        elif money < total_price:
            print("You do not have enough money")
            print("You cannot buy that many"+str(item_name)+"s")

    print(str(money)+" dollars left in your wallet") input("do want to buy somehing else: ")

    if input() != "yes":
        break
```

This loops the content of the while loop. The break command if you enter "yes" jumps out of the loop and stops everything.

Edit: Wait... The code changed, while I wrote my answer. Nevertheless, put everthing in a while-Loop and it should work

Edit2: Fixed a mistake, money shouldn't be set to 20 in each loop, and the items don't need to be reset either.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code inside a class method and call that class again.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is execute the for loop *while* a *condition* is **true**. Luckily Python has this functionality in the form of while loops.

```
money = 20
items = {'apple': 2, 'banana': 4, 'orange': 6}
while money > 0:
    for item_name in items:
        print('--------------------------------------------------')

        print("You have "+ str(money)+" dollars in your wallet")

        print('Each ' + item_name + ' costs ' + str(items[item_name]) + '  dollars')

        input_count = input('How many ' + item_name + 's do you want?: ')
        print('You will buy ' + input_count + ' ' + item_name + 's')

        count = int(input_count)
        total_price = items[item_name] * count
        print('The total price is ' + str(total_price) + ' dollars')


        if money >= total_price:
            print("You have bought "+str(input_count)+" "+str(item_name)+"s")

            money = money-total_price
        elif money < total_price:
            print("You do not have enough money")
            print("You cannot buy that many"+str(item_name)+"s")

    print(str(money)+" dollars left in your wallet")
    user_input = input("do want to buy something else: ")

    if user_input != "yes":
        break
```

After the for loop finishes the program asks the user if they want to buy something else. If they have no money the while loop condition will be false and this means the program will end because there is no code after the while loop.

Hope this helped!